# Scala SBT elasticsearch-hadoop unresolved dependency

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, elasticsearch-hadoop

When adding dependency `libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "5.1.1"` and refreshing project, I get many unresolved dependencies(cascading, org.pentaho,...).

However if I add another dependency, like `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"` it works and I can use the library in my scala files.

So, is the problem coming from elasticsearch-hadoop ? I'm using SBT 0.13.13 but also tried with 0.13.8.

I took the dependency from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/5.1.1 I know that for some dependencies you need to add the repository aswell (resolvers += ...), but here it doesn't seems to need a repo.

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your `build.sbt` file:

```
resolvers += "conjars.org" at "http://conjars.org/repo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can update your .sbt file

```
name:="HelloSparkApp"
version:="1.0"
scalaVersion:="2.10.4"
libraryDependencies+="org.apache.spark"%%"spark-core"%"1.5.2"
```

And execute the below commands from the project directory

```
sbt clean
sbt package
sbt eclipse
```